# Use two different LSTM cell in Tensorflow

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, lstm, machine-translation

I am building a neural machine translator, and I have to use two **different** LSTM cells (one for the encoder, and one for the decode).

The two cells have differents shapes:

- the encoder (first one) is fed with the token of the input sentence and produces a state vector
- the decoder (second one) is fed with the previous state vector, and the tokens generated by itself

I writed this in Tensorflow, and when I run the script, I got the following error (raised during the decoder phase):

```
  outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(cell_backward, inputs, initial_state=initial_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 158, in rnn
    (output, state) = call_cell()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 145, in <lambda>
    call_cell = lambda: cell(input_, state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py", line 520, in __call__
    dtype, self._num_unit_shards)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py", line 357, in _get_concat_variable
    sharded_variable = _get_sharded_variable(name, shape, dtype, num_shards)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py", line 387, in _get_sharded_variable
    dtype=dtype))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 732, in get_variable
    partitioner=partitioner, validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 596, in get_variable
    partitioner=partitioner, validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 161, in get_variable
    caching_device=caching_device, validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 437, in _get_single_variable
    name, "".join(traceback.format_list(tb))))
ValueError: Variable backward/RNN/LSTMCell/W_0 already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:

  File "/home/alexis/Documents/NMT/NMT.py", line 88, in dense_to_vector_state
    outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(cell_forward, inputs, initial_state=initial_state)
```

How can I explicitly specify that I want to create a totally new LSTM cell ?

Thanks in advance !

Alexis

Answer (score 1):

Use variable scopes

```
with tf.variable_scope('enc'):
  cell_enc = LSTMCell(hidden_size)
with tf.variable_scope('dec'):
  cell_dec = LSTMCell(hidden_size)
```

Comment: This answer needs some explanations.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to do machine translation.  Here is my encoder and decoder.  You just need to use different variable scopes for each rnn.  Rather than using the MultiRNNCell cell for the encoder I unroll each layer manually which lets me alternate directions between layers.  See how each layer gets its own scope.

```
with tf.variable_scope('encoder'):
    rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(512, num_proj = 256, state_is_tuple = True)
    for level in range(3):
        with tf.variable_scope('level_%d' % level) as scope:
            state = [tf.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, sz)) for sz in rnn_cell.state_size]
            for t in range(TIME_STEPS) if level % 2 else reversed(range(TIME_STEPS)):
                y[t], state = rnn_cell(y[t], state)
                scope.reuse_variables()


with tf.variable_scope('decoder') as scope:
    rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell \
    ([
        tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(512, num_proj = 256, state_is_tuple = True),
        tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(512, num_proj = WORD_VEC_SIZE, state_is_tuple = True)
    ], state_is_tuple = True)

    state = [[tf.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, sz)) for sz in sz_outer] for sz_outer in rnn_cell.state_size]

    W_soft = tf.get_variable('W_soft', shape = (NWORDS, WORD_VEC_SIZE), initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0.0, 1 / np.sqrt(WORD_VEC_SIZE)))
    b_soft = tf.get_variable('b_soft', shape = (NWORDS,), initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0.0, 0.01))
    cost = 0
    output = [None] * TIME_STEPS

    for t in range(TIME_STEPS):
        if t:
            last = y_[t - 1] if TRAINING else y[t - 1]
        else:
            last = tf.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, WORD_VEC_SIZE))

        y[t] = tf.concat(1, (y[t], last))
        y[t], state = rnn_cell(y[t], state)

        cost += tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(W_soft, b_soft, y[t], target_output[:, t : t + 1], 1000, NWORDS))
        output[t] = tf.reshape(tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y[t], W_soft, transpose_b = True) + b_soft), (BATCH_SIZE, 1, NWORDS))

        scope.reuse_variables()

    output = tf.concat(1, output)
    cost /= TIME_STEPS
```

Comment: Are the gradients backpropagated without a symbolic while_loop? From what I read you are not supposed to unroll manually in tf. The proper way is to either use tf.scan or tf.while_loop. Correct me if I'm wrong.